# Ionic - How to show custom buttons defined in [selectOptions] on ion-select?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, alert, ionic4, ion-select

I am trying to define custom buttons on an ion-select by passing in options in the [selectOptions] like this:

HTML:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedSkypeUser" [selectOptions]="getSelectOptions()">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of skypeUsers" [value]="user.name"> 
        {{user.name}}
    </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

TS:

```
private skypeUserButtons = {
    title: "Skype users",
    subTitle: "Select the user you want to change",
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {}
        },
        {
            text: 'Delete',
            handler: () => {
                this.deleteSkypeUser();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Add new user',
            handler: () => {
                this.addSkypeUser();
            }
        }
    ]
};

getSelectOptions() {
    return this.skypeUserButtons;
}
```

The title and subTitle are showing fine, but the buttons are just the default buttons. What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same doubt.

Maybe there's no way to do that.

Comment: I have fixed it in a different way. Can post the answer later.

Comment: It would help so much! I'm need so much too execute an action when closing the select that I'm ever considerating to create my own select component from scratch.

Comment: Thats basically what I did. I'll post now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering the question completely, but its a work-around that is actually working. (Maybe the only solution as for now).

I have just created a simple button that triggers the pop-up, but this can be an element styled to look like a regular select, and show the selected option or whatever you want:

HTML:

```
<button ion-button icon-left round (click)="showUserDialog()">
    Edit users
</button>
```

TS:

```
showUserDialog() {
  let inputs = [];
  let users = this.skypeUsers;
  users.forEach(user => {
      inputs.push({
          type: 'radio',
          label: user.name,
          value: user.name
      });
  });

  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: "Select user",
    inputs,
    buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        },
        {
            'Delete',
            handler: data => {
                // data == selected user.name (value)
            }
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Add new user',
        handler: () => {
            // Trigger logic to add new user
            this.createNewUser()

            // Return true to close the alert - false to keep it open
            return true;
        }
    }]
  });

  alert.present();
}
```